# php intl parameter Formatting not working with yii2

Tags: php, yii2, centos, centos7, intl

I have used https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-i18n#parameter-formatting

but on my server, it displayed like a full string without any effect of intl.

my code is like:

```
echo \Yii::t('app', 'There {n,plural,=0{are no cats} =1{is one cat} other{are # cats}}!', ['n' => $n]);
```

expected result:

```
// When $n = 0, it may produce "There are no cats!"
// When $n = 1, it may produce "There is one cat!"
// When $n = 42, it may produce "There are 42 cats!"
```

but it displays the whole expression here without any effect

here is the php info
[image]

Comment: I think your ICU version is low. See what documenation says: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-i18n#setup-environment
`It is also recommended that you use an ICU version equal or greater than version 49`

Comment: @vvpanchev PHP: 7.3.27 ICU: 4.2.1
Warning: Use of undefined constant INTL_ICU_DATA_VERSION - assumed 'INTL_ICU_DATA_VERSION' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: @vvpanchev fixed by upgrading ICU version on the server, thanks a lot buddy